# Smooth maps from given manifold into the complex plane: is there a "product rule"?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-numbers, differential-topology, frechet-derivative

Suppose that we have two smooth functions from some **real** manifold $X$ into the complex plane $\mathbb C$:

$$f,g: X \to \mathbb C.$$

I'm vaguely wondering, if we treat $\mathbb C$ as a plane equipped with a flat metric, if there's a relationship between (complex) multiplication and the Frechet derivative map, i.e. a kind of "product rule" which relates $h(x):= f(x)g(x)$ to $f$ and $g$.

My super naive thinking would be that something like $(\ast)$ holds:

$$\phantom{(\ast)} \qquad D_x h = g(x)D_x f + f(x) D_x g \qquad (\ast)$$

(where $D_x f : T_x X \to T_{f(x)} \mathbb C$ denotes the Frechet derivative of $f$, for example),

but this doesn't even make sense, as $D_x f$, $D_x h$ and $D_x g$ can all land in different tangent spaces. This leads to my question.

**Question:** Is there any meaningful way to relate the derivative map of $h$ in terms of $f$ and $g$, given that there one can identify tangent spaces of $\mathbb C$ using isometries?

**Failing that**, is it possible to at least estimate the operator norm of $D_x h$ from that of $D_x f$ and $D_x g$?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What is the derivative of the map $\mathbb C\times \mathbb C\rightarrow C$ that takes the product? How can you use this and the chain rule?

Comment: @ThomasRot that seems like a very reasonable suggestion. Is it possible to use this to obtain something coordinate free?

Comment: @rschwieb I'm not assuming anything like that because I don't know what it means. Would it be at all helpful to assume that they are?

Comment: Spensers argument is what I had in mind. This is reasonably coordinate free

Comment: I hadn't seen it until now! Please ignore that

Comment: @Ben What I meant to ask is if $X$ is supposed to be a complex manifold and the function is smooth in the complex sense.  Isn't complex smoothness slightly different than what the Frechet derivative does for real manifolds?

Comment: @rschwieb I imagine so. To clarify I thought of $X$ only as a real manifold. 

Re: Complex Smoothness, In reading I've only gone as far as Riemann Surfaces. In which case is complex smoothness merely just analyticity? (Certainly this is much more than I can reasonably ask for.)

Comment: @Ben If $X$ is a real manifold, I'm not really sure what using $\mathbb C$ changes. Why not just say $\mathbb R^2$? I'm not knowledgeable about derivatives on manifolds, but it seems like Munkres' *Analysis on Manifolds* p 350 in googlebooks might be a source?

Comment: @rschwieb At the very least it made the definition of multiplication easier. I imagine also there are many contexts in which, if $X$ is some meaningful state space, one would want consider not only real but complex observables. And people like rings, don't they?

Comment: @Ben In this case, using $\mathbb C$ *caused* confusion, for me anyway. I like rings [more than most people](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com) but I don't know what $\mathbb C$ contributes if $X$ is a real manifold. I see you're using complex multiplication in your definition of the proposed rule now though. Now I'm back to not knowing how this works with the regular Frechet derivative vs the complex derivative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{C}$ is a vector space, its tangent spaces can be canonically identified with itself. Hence, for each $x\in X$, we may view $D_xf$ as a map
$$D_xf:T_xX\to\mathbb{C}.$$
Then,
$$D_x(fg)=f(x)D_xg+g(x)D_xf.$$
To prove this formula, note that $fg=m\circ(f\times g)$ where $m:\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is multiplication and $f\times g:X\to\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ is the map $(f\times g)(x)=(f(x),g(x))$. Then, $D_x(f\times g)=D_xf\times D_xg:T_xX\to\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$. Moreover, after identifying $T_z\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{C}$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ we have that for all $(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$,
$$D_{(z_1,z_2)}m:\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C},\quad (a,b)\mapsto z_1b+z_2a$$
since
$$(D_{(z_1,z_2)}m)(a,b)=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}(z_1+at)(z_2+bt)=z_1b+z_2a.$$
Combining this with the chain rule, we get
$$D_x(fg)=D_x(m\circ(f\times g))=D_{(f(x),g(x))}m\circ(D_xf\times D_xg)=f(x)D_xg+g(x)D_xf.$$

Comment: Marvellous! I believe the canonical identification (plus inexperience) was what was tripping me up there. That does seem jolly reasonable.

Comment: @Ben My pleasure. By the way, if $V$ is a vector space and $v\in V$, the canonical identification between $V$ and $T_vV$ is the linear isomorphism $V\to T_vV$ which sends a vector $w$ to the derivation $C^\infty(V)\to\mathbb{R}:f\mapsto\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f(v+tw)$.

Comment: Of course! That makes a lot of sense